# How do I enable IP-forwarding in MacOS X?

Tags: mac-osx, iptables, ipfw, ip-forwarding

What is the correct way to enable IP-forwarding in MacOS X?

More specifically, what is the MacOS X command line quivalent of the following two Linux commands:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
iptables -A FORWARD -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You're doing two things there.

1. Enabling IP forwarding.  The OS X equivalent might be:

   ```
   sysctl -w net.inet.ip.forwarding=1
   ```

   ...but since I don't know exactly what you're trying to do, this might be technically correct but unhelpful.
2. Adding a largely unnecessary firewall rule.  If you haven't changed the default policy for your FORWARD chain (`iptables -P FORWARD ...`), then this rule does nothing.

   OS X uses the `pf` firewall tools.  Try [here](https://murusfirewall.com/Documentation/OS%20X%20PF%20Manual.pdf)

   Prior to 10.7 Lion, OS X used the `ipfw` firewall tools, which are well documented all over the net.  Try [here](http://macdevcenter.com/pub/a/mac/2005/03/15/firewall.html), or [here](http://www.macshadows.com/kb/index.php?title=Firewall_Tunning_on_Mac_OS_X)

Comment: This is exactly what I needed to enable a proper switch on my Bridge virtual interface. Catalina.